# Редактирование модуля комментариев

Tags: drupal, cms

Здравствуйте! Я пишу сайт,уже разместил его на бесплатном хостинге, вот его адрес orange.hol.es . Я разрешил оставлять комментарии на главной странице. Мне не нравится,что в месте где публикуется автор написано много ненужного текста и снизу под тексовым полем мне не к чему более подробная информация о текстовых форматах. Подскажите,пожалуйста, где это можно исправить описание публикации автора и убрать более подробную информацию о текст форматах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убираем инфу о форматах:
В template.php пишем

```
/**
 * Override default theme_filter_tips_more_info().
 */
function THEMENAME_filter_tips_more_info() {
  return '';
}

function THEMENAME_filter_tips($tips, $long = FALSE, $extra = '') {
 return '';
 }
```

Информацию о авторе комментария:
В comment.tpl.php где (submitted)

```
<?php print $author; // Имя автора?>
      <?php print format_interval(time() - $comment->created, 2) . ' ' . ('назад');// сделает даты в виде 20 минут назад. ?>
      <?php print $permalink // постоянная ссылка ?>
      <?php if ($new): //выделить новые комментарии ?>
          <mark class="new"><?php print $new; ?></mark>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Не могу убрать инфу о форматах. Расскажите подробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: http://kozyrkov.ru/3306-ubiraem-podskazki-formata-vvoda-v-drupal-7.html

Answer (score 0):

Нужно править шаблоны (файлы типа *.tpl.php) в теме сайта, либо писать hook-функции для перехвата вывода автора.